# Blazor field gets null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor

I have this code in blazor:
It's just a simple method to update the div each second:

```
<div style="font-size:50px">@dailyCases.ToString("0,0.00")</div>

@code
{
private double dailyCases;
private bool needsUpdate = false;
private CovidDataManager covidManager;

protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("init");
    dailyCases = await updateData();
    await StartCounter();
}

private Task StartCounter()
{
    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    timer.Elapsed += async (sender, e) =>
    {
        dailyCases = await update();
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    };

    timer.Start();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private async Task<double> updateData()
{
    var httpResponse = await covidRepository.GetYesterdayData("FRANCE");
    var covidDailyInfoDTO = mapper.Map<Covid19Portal.Shared.DTO.CovidDailyInfoDTO>(httpResponse.Response);
    var covidManager = new Covid19Portal.Shared.CovidDataManager(covidDailyInfoDTO);
    return await Task.FromResult(covidManager.SickUpToNow);
}

private async Task<double> update()
{
    return await Task.FromResult(covidManager.SickUpToNow);
    //return await Task.FromResult(covidManager.SickUpToNow);
}
```

}

I get and error that covidManager is null after update gets called.
Any idea why?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're ever setting a value for `private CovidDataManager covidManager;`

Comment: i do here:  var covidManager = new Covid19Portal.Shared.CovidDataManager(covidDailyInfoDTO);

Comment: No, since you have `var` in front of it you're declaring a variable that's only visible to the scope of the `updateData()` method. If you remove the `var`, that should set the private field

Comment: This is why I use Pascal Case for private members :) @devNull add it as an answer so it can be accepted.